# Passing image pointer to assembly by dll

Tags: assembly, imagefilter

I have data save as r,g,ba,r,g,b,a,... when i give a small image like 1000x500px to asm everything is good but when i want to give him larger photo 5000x3000 it returns me memory access error what can be the reasone? and it will help when i start to use r,g,b,r,g,b,r,g,b data?

Asm code:

```
.data
  LaplaceMask BYTE 9 DUP (0,-1,0,-1,4,-1,0,-1,0) ;Maska dla filtru laplace
  ;LaplaceEXAMPLE BYTE 9 DUP (10,10,10,10,100,10,10,10,10) ;Do testowanie liczenia nowej wartosci piksela 
.code

_DllMainCRTStartup proc parameter1:DWORD, parameter2:DWORD, parameter3:DWORD  ;entry point
    MOV EAX, 1
    RET
_DllMainCRTStartup endp

GetNewPixelValue PROC
   
    PXOR XMM0,XMM0
    MOVQ XMM0, QWORD PTR [LaplaceMask] ;przeniesienie wartosci maski do rejestru XMM0
    ;MOVQ XMM10, QWORD PTR [LaplaceEXAMPLE] ; Testowanie obliczania wartosci piksela
    MOVDQU XMM10, XMM2 ;przeniesienie wektora koloru, ktory chcemy liczyc do wektora XMM10
    PMOVSXBW XMM0, XMM0 ;konwersja na word
   
    PMADDWD XMM0, XMM10 ;monozenie dwoch wektorow i sumowanie parami
    PHADDD XMM0, XMM0   ;sumuje elemenety parami 
    PHADDD XMM0, XMM0   ;sumuje elemenety parami
   
    MOVD ECX, XMM0    ;zapisanie wyniku do ECX 
    MOVSXD RDX, ECX ;przeniesienie wartosc do rejestru RDX
    
    ;Sprawdzanie czy wartosc jest z przedzialu 0-255
    CMP RDX, 0
    JL UnderZero 
    CMP RDX, 255
    JG Overflow 
    JMP DONE
    UnderZero:
    MOV RDX, 0 
    JMP DONE
    Overflow:
    MOV RDX, 255 
    DONE:
    RET
GetNewPixelValue ENDP

LaplaceApply PROC EXPORT
    
    MOV R11, RCX ; Wskaznik na tablice wejsciowa
    MOV R12, RDX ; Szerokosc obrazka (zapisana jako r b g a r g b a r g b a)
    MOV R13, R8 ; Wysokosc obrazka
    MOV R14, R9 ; Wskaznik na tablice wyjsciowa
    XOR RAX,RAX
    MOV RAX, QWORD PTR [RSP+40] ;przesuniecie dla threadow
    ADD R11, RAX
    ADD R14, RAX

    XOR RAX, RAX ;COLOMN_LOOP iterator (i=0)
    INC RAX ;i=1 zeby zaczac od 2 wiersza

COLOMN_LOOP:

    XOR RBX, RBX ; ROW_LOOP iterator (j=0)
    ADD RBX, 4 ;Przeskakiwanie co 4 wartosc sa w formacie r, g, b , a
    
    ROW_LOOP:

    ;Lewy Gorny
    XOR RCX, RCX 
    XOR RDX, RDX 
    PXOR XMM1, XMM1

    ;kolor czerwony
    MOV RDX, RAX ;przenosimy wartosc i, zeby jej potem nie stracic
    DEC RDX ;zmniejszamy o jeden bo chcemy wartosc z pierwszzego wiersza a jestesmy w drugim
    IMUL RDX, R12 ; mnozymy razy szerokosc aby dostac sie do odpowiedniego indexu
    ADD RDX, RBX ; dodajemy iterator j 
    SUB RDX, 4 ; odejmujemy 4 aby cofnac sie do chcianej wartosc poprzedniego piksela 

    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX] ; wartosc piksela zapisujemy w rejestrze CL
    PSLLDQ XMM7, 2 ; przesuwamy rejestr o 2 
    MOVD XMM1, ECX ; przenosimy zawartosc rejestru do rejestry XMM1
    ADDPS XMM7, XMM1 ; dodanie do wektora ktory przechowuje wartosc piksel branych do obliczen 

    ;Reszta piksel analogicznie rozni sie jedynie przejsciem do poszczegolnych pikseli
    ;kolor zielony
    PXOR XMM1,XMM1
    XOR RCX,RCX
    INC RDX
    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM8, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM8, XMM1

    ;kolor niebieski
    PXOR XMM1,XMM1
    XOR RCX,RCX
    INC RDX
    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM9, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM9, XMM1

    ;Srodek Gora
    XOR RCX, RCX 
    XOR RDX, RDX 
    PXOR XMM1, XMM1

    ;kolor czerwony
    MOV RDX, RAX 
    DEC RDX
    IMUL RDX, R12
    ADD RDX, RBX

    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM7, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM7,XMM1

    ;kolor zielony
    PXOR XMM1,XMM1
    XOR RCX,RCX
    INC RDX
    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM8, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM8, XMM1

    ;kolor niebieski
    PXOR XMM1,XMM1
    XOR RCX,RCX
    INC RDX
    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM9, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM9, XMM1
    

    ;Prawo Gora
    XOR RCX, RCX 
    XOR RDX, RDX 
    PXOR XMM1, XMM1

    ;kolor czerwony
    MOV RDX, RAX 
    DEC RDX
    IMUL RDX, R12
    ADD RDX, RBX
    ADD RDX, 4

    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM7, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM7,XMM1

    ;kolor zielony
    PXOR XMM1,XMM1
    XOR RCX,RCX
    INC RDX
    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM8, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM8, XMM1

    ;kolor niebieski
    PXOR XMM1,XMM1
    XOR RCX,RCX
    INC RDX
    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM9, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM9, XMM1

    ;Lewo Srodek
    XOR RCX, RCX 
    XOR RDX, RDX 
    PXOR XMM1, XMM1

    ;kolor czerwony
    MOV RDX, RAX
    IMUL RDX, R12
    ADD RDX, RBX
    SUB RDX,4
    
    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM7, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM7,XMM1

    ;kolor zielony
    PXOR XMM1,XMM1
    XOR RCX,RCX
    INC RDX
    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM8, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM8, XMM1

    ;kolor niebieski
    PXOR XMM1,XMM1
    XOR RCX,RCX
    INC RDX
    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM9, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM9, XMM1

    ;Srodek 
    XOR RCX, RCX 
    XOR RDX, RDX 
    XOR R8,R8
    PXOR XMM1, XMM1

    
    ;kolor czerwony
    MOV RDX, RAX 
    IMUL RDX, R12
    ADD RDX, RBX
    MOV R8, RDX
    
    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM7, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM7,XMM1

    ;kolor zielony
    PXOR XMM1,XMM1
    XOR RCX,RCX
    INC RDX
    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM8, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM8, XMM1

    ;kolor niebiskie
    PXOR XMM1,XMM1
    XOR RCX,RCX
    INC RDX
    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM9, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM9, XMM1

    ;Srodek prawo
    XOR RCX, RCX 
    XOR RDX, RDX 
    PXOR XMM1, XMM1

    ;kolor czerwony
    MOV RDX, RAX 
    IMUL RDX, R12
    ADD RDX, RBX
    ADD RDX, 4

    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM7, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM7,XMM1

    ;kolor zielony
    PXOR XMM1,XMM1
    XOR RCX,RCX
    INC RDX
    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM8, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM8, XMM1

    ;kolor niebieski
    PXOR XMM1,XMM1
    XOR RCX,RCX
    INC RDX
    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM9, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM9, XMM1

    ;Lewo Dol
    XOR RCX, RCX
    XOR RDX, RDX
    PXOR XMM1, XMM1

    ;kolor czerwony
    MOV RDX, RAX 
    INC RDX 
    IMUL RDX, R12
    ADD RDX, RBX
    SUB RDX, 4
    
    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM7, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM7,XMM1

    ;kolor zielony
    PXOR XMM1,XMM1
    XOR RCX,RCX
    INC RDX
    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM8, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM8, XMM1

    ;kolor niebiski
    PXOR XMM1,XMM1
    XOR RCX,RCX
    INC RDX
    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM9, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM9, XMM1

    ;Dol Srodek
    XOR RCX, RCX 
    XOR RDX, RDX 
    PXOR XMM1, XMM1

    ;kolor czerwony
    MOV RDX, RAX 
    INC RDX
    IMUL RDX, R12
    ADD RDX, RBX

    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM7, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM7,XMM1

    ;kolor zielony
    PXOR XMM1,XMM1
    XOR RCX,RCX
    INC RDX
    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM8, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM8, XMM1

    ;kolor niebieski 
    PXOR XMM1,XMM1
    XOR RCX,RCX
    INC RDX
    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM9, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM9, XMM1

    ;Dol Prawo
    XOR RCX, RCX 
    XOR RDX, RDX 
    PXOR XMM1, XMM1

    ;kolor czerwony
    MOV RDX, RAX
    INC RDX
    IMUL RDX, R12
    ADD RDX, RBX
    ADD RDX, 4

    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM7, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM7,XMM1

    ;kolor zielony
    PXOR XMM1,XMM1
    XOR RCX,RCX
    INC RDX
    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM8, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM8, XMM1

    ;kolor niebiski
    PXOR XMM1,XMM1
    XOR RCX,RCX
    INC RDX
    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX]
    PSLLDQ XMM9, 2
    MOVD XMM1, ECX
    ADDPS XMM9, XMM1

    ;Czerwony
    PXOR XMM2,XMM2
    XOR RDX, RDX

    MOVDQU XMM2, XMM7 ; przensienie wartosc pikseli ktore bedziemy liczyli do wektora XMM2
    CALL GetNewPixelValue ; wywoanie procedury
    MOV BYTE PTR [R14+R8], DL ; przypisanie nowej wartosc 
   
    ;zielony
    PXOR XMM2,XMM2
    XOR RDX, RDX

    MOVDQU XMM2, XMM8 ; przensienie wartosc pikseli ktore bedziemy liczyli do wektora XMM2
    CALL GetNewPixelValue ; wywoanie procedury
    INC R8 ;przejscie do kolejnej skladowej
    MOV BYTE PTR [R14+R8], DL; przypisanie nowej wartosc 
    
    ;niebiski
    PXOR XMM2,XMM2 
    XOR RDX, RDX

    MOVDQU XMM2, XMM9 ; przensienie wartosc pikseli ktore bedziemy liczyli do wektora XMM2
    CALL GetNewPixelValue ; wywoanie procedury
    INC R8;przejscie do kolejnej skladowej
    MOV BYTE PTR [R14+R8], DL; przypisanie nowej wartosc 
    
    INC R8;przejscie do kolejnej skladowej
    MOV BYTE PTR [R14+R8], 255 ; zapisanie wartosc a na 255 

    ADD RBX, 4 ;j+=4
    CMP RBX, R12 
    JL ROW_LOOP; j < szerokość obrazka

    INC RAX ;i++
    CMP RAX, R13 
    JL COLOMN_LOOP ; i < wysokość obrazka 

    ;USUWAC OBRAMOWANIA 
   
    XOR RAX, RAX
    MOV RAX, R12
    IMUL RAX, R13
    DEC RAX
    XOR RBX, RBX

    BOTTOM_EDGE:
        XOR RCX, RCX
        XOR RDX, RDX
        DEC RAX 
        MOV RDX, RAX
        SUB RDX, R12
        MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R14+RDX]
        MOV BYTE PTR [R14+RAX], CL
        INC RBX
    CMP RBX, R12
    JNE BOTTOM_EDGE

    XOR RAX, RAX
    XOR RBX, RBX 
    TOP_EDGE:
        XOR RCX, RCX
        XOR RDX, RDX
        MOV RCX, RAX
        ADD RCX, R12
        MOV DL, BYTE PTR [R14+RCX]
        MOV BYTE PTR [R14+RAX], DL
        INC RAX
    CMP RAX,R12
    JNE TOP_EDGE

    RET 

LaplaceApply ENDP

END
```

i try to give larger or smaller photo but there was a small limit where it is starting crushing and returing memory access errors

Comment: Which instruction faults?  With what register values / what address is it accessing?  Did allocation fail in the caller?

Comment: Also, why are you writing this by hand in asm if you're doing stuff like `pxor xmm0,xmm0` / `movq xmm0, [mem]` / `pmovsxbw xmm0, xmm0` (3 uops) instead of `pmovsxbw xmm0, [mem]` (1 uop micro-fused)?  `movq` to an XMM register doesn't have a false dependency so xor-zeroing is just a waste of a uop.  Also, if you call this small function often, it's probably worthwhile to load a 16-byte constant instead of spending a shuffle uop.  Also, if you're going to clamp to 0-255, there's no point in sign-extending to 64-bit, just use 32-bit operand-size.  A compiler would do at least as good a job.

Comment: Also, if you generate multiple pixels at once (which is what `phaddd` is for: multiple horizontal reductions in parallel to get a vector of 4 dword pixel values), you could then  packi back to bytes with saturation; `packssdw` to saturate to SHORT_MIN / SHORT_MAX, then `packuswb` to saturate signed input to `0 - 255`.  So each `phaddd` (2 shuffle + 1 add) would be getting 2x or 4x as much useful work done, and feeding SIMD packing instead of scalar extract and byte stores.  (You can do that with intrinsics equally well.)

Comment: @PeterCordes It depends but usually ;kolor czerwony
    MOV RDX, RAX
    INC RDX
    IMUL RDX, R12
    ADD RDX, RBX
    ADD RDX, 4

    MOV CL, BYTE PTR [R11+RDX] on this move it is last section of reading pixel bottom right

Comment: Ok, and is `R11+RDX` outside the input image when that happens?  If so, there's your bug, work backwards to find out how that happened, like why you ran too many loop iterations.  Note that memory protection works at 4K granularity, so reading past the end of an array don't fault if you don't read too far; that could still have been happening with the smaller image sizes that happen to work, like maybe one row too far is only 500 bytes, usually not into the next page.

Comment: Valgrind might help identifying when you read past the end of a buffer.  Or pass a size like 1024x512 in a buffer that's aligned by 4096, so hopefully the following page is unmapped and any access past the end will fault.

Comment: Also, BTW, `XOR RCX, RCX / mov cl, [mem]` is just a slow way to write `movzx ecx, byte [mem]`.  And I don't understand `ADDPS` (single-precision float) on integer data where you're doing stuff like shifting left by 2 bytes, or loading a zero-extended byte.  If it works at all, is it because your data is all small non-negative integers that work as bit-patterns for subnormal floats?  That's going to be extremely slow on some CPUs, and worse than `paddd` on all CPUs.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for you answear. I make this thing which slow down my program because it is my first asm project, so thanks one more time because i learnt a lot from your answear

Comment: I'd recommend writing in C or C++ with intrinsics, at least as a first version.  It's interesting to *look at* the asm to see what's going on, or use that as a starting point if you have some optimization ideas that the compiler won't do for you.   ([How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) / Matt Godbolt's CppCon2017 talk [“What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4).  OTOH, Intel's intrinsics are much easier to understand when you know what asm you want them to compile to.

Comment: @PeterCordes i typed in c++ because i have to compare time it is c++ and asm dll and ui and threads in c#

Comment: C# has SSE/AVX intrinsics as well.  Hopefully with intrinsics like `Sse41.ConvertToVector128Int16(Byte*)` for memory-source `pmovzx`, you can get the code-gen you want. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86.sse41.converttovector128int16?view=net-7.0  (In C++ you have to depend on the compiler to fold a `_mm_loadu_si64()` load +  `_mm_cvtepu8_epi16(__m128i)` into a memory source operand for `pmovzxbw`). But C# makes it a bit less easy than C++ to see the compiler-generated asm, although https://sharplab.io/ does do it.